# Problemas con Framework

Tags: windows-server, framework

Hoy les vengo a preguntar una cuestión sobre el **Framework 4.7.2**.
Igual es una preguntar estúpida pero sería de agradecer alguna aclaración al problema que tengo y es el siguiente: ¿Se podría utilizar en un **Windows Server 2003** el **Framework 4.7.2**? En caso afirmativo, podrían guiarme a cómo instalarlo?

He estado buscando información al respecto y he descubierto que lo "mínimo" que acepta el **Framework 4.7.2** es Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (x64).

Gracias por la ayuda, un saludo

Comment: ¿Framework 4.7.2? ¿Será que te refieres a [.NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472)? En todo caso, leer los requisitos del sistema en la [página de descarga](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=55167) te orientará. Claramente Windows Server 2003 no es soportado. También te sugiero leer [ask]. Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras Gracias por tu respuesta. Llevo poco tiempo por estos lares y aún no se mucho. Sobre el problema estuve ya investigando donde tu dices y demás antes de postear por aquí,  más que nada es si hay alguna otra forma de "forzar" a que se pudiese instalar esa versión de .NET Framework en Server 2003.

Comment: **si hay alguna otra forma de "forzar" a que se pudiese instalar esa versión de .NET Framework en Server 2003** La verdad no lo creo, y en caso de que existiese, no lo recomiendo. Saludos